# JSON invalido cuando viene de consulta php mysql, pero funciona cuando es llamado de formato json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Después de leer cientos de problemas similares y sin poder encontrar la solución al problema, pregunto lo siguiente. Tengo un archivo php en donde se listan los datos por **datatables**, que vienen por ajax de otro archivo php.

El problema es que cuando quiero llamar los datos de ese archivo, se produce un error:

> DataTables warning: table id=listado - Invalid JSON response. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1.

Realicé los pasos de verificacion del correcto formato de mi cadena JSON en varios validadores, entre ellos https://jsonlint.com/, dandome como resultado, un JSON valido.

Cuando guardo mi cadena JSON generada y lo guardo en otro archivo, por ejemplo, **prueba.json** y lo llamo desde **datatables** a través de ajax, funciona todo bien. Llevo 10 horas con lo mismo y no he podido encontrar la solución. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme, se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Esta es mi cadena JSON:

```
{
"data": [{
    "0": "8",
    "folio": "8",
    "1": null,
    "etapa": null,
    "2": "2018",
    "ano": "2018",
    "3": "Diciembre",
    "nombre_mes": "Diciembre",
    "4": "Corona Zirconio PFP",
    "procedimiento": "Corona Zirconio PFP",
    "5": "56000",
    "valor": "56000",
    "6": "2018-12-04",
    "fecha_envio": "2018-12-04",
    "7": "12",
    "id": "12"
}, {
    "0": "14",
    "folio": "14",
    "1": "1",
    "etapa": "1",
    "2": "2018",
    "ano": "2018",
    "3": "Diciembre",
    "nombre_mes": "Diciembre",
    "4": "Corona Zirconio PFP",
    "procedimiento": "Corona Zirconio PFP",
    "5": "56000",
    "valor": "56000",
    "6": "2018-12-05",
    "fecha_envio": "2018-12-05",
    "7": "12",
    "id": "12"
}, {
    "0": "15",
    "folio": "15",
    "1": "1",
    "etapa": "1",
    "2": "2018",
    "ano": "2018",
    "3": "Diciembre",
    "nombre_mes": "Diciembre",
    "4": "Espiga Mu\u00f1on Colado",
    "procedimiento": "Espiga Mu\u00f1on Colado",
    "5": "42000",
    "valor": "42000",
    "6": "2018-12-18",
    "fecha_envio": "2018-12-18",
    "7": "12",
    "id": "12"
}, {
    "0": "14",
    "folio": "14",
    "1": "3",
    "etapa": "3",
    "2": "2018",
    "ano": "2018",
    "3": "Diciembre",
    "nombre_mes": "Diciembre",
    "4": "Incrustacion Metalica Overlay",
    "procedimiento": "Incrustacion Metalica Overlay",
    "5": "70000",
    "valor": "70000",
    "6": "2018-12-29",
    "fecha_envio": "2018-12-29",
    "7": "12",
    "id": "12"
}]
}
```

Este es el código que genera el JSON desde php:

```
function getArraySQL($sql){

$conexion = connectDB();

    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); 

$rawdata = array(); 

$i=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $rawdata['data'][$i] = array(
    'col_1' => $row['folio'],
    'col_2' => $row['etapa'],
    'col_3' => $row['ano'],
    'col_4' => $row['nombre_mes'],
    'col_5' => $row['procedimiento'],
    'col_6' => $row['valor'],
    'col_7' => $row['fecha_envio']
  );
    $i++;
}

disconnectDB($conexion); 

return $rawdata;
}

    $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
    echo json_encode($myArray);
```

y asi se llama desde datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#listado').DataTable({
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "jsonprueba.php",
        "type" : "POST"
    },
    "columns" : [
    {
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data": "col_1"
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data": null,
      "render": function (data, type, row, meta){
        var etapa = row['col_2'];
        if (etapa == null){
          return 'N/A';
        }else{
          return ' '+etapa+' ';
        }
      }
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data": "col_3"
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data" : "col_4"
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data" : "col_5"
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data" : "col_6"
    },{
      "sClass": "alignRight",
      "data" : "col_7",
      "render": function (data) {
        var dateString = new Date(data);
        return moment.utc(dateString).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      }
    }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
    {
        'targets': 5,
        "render": function (data) {
           return FormatValue(data);
        }
    }
    ],
      "iDisplayLength": 25,
      "language": {
      "emptyTable": "SIN REGISTROS",
      "infoEmpty": "",
        "search": "Buscar _INPUT_ ",
        "info": "Mostrando Pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ Registros",
        "infoFiltered": "(Busqueda Desde _MAX_ Registros Totales)",
        "paginate": {
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    },
  });
});
```

Si falta información para aclarar la pregunta, con gusto la agregaré.
De antemano, muchas gracias como siempre a todos.

Comment: Oye, pero, ¿en qué parte de tu código estás creando a lo que tu llamas la "Cadeja JSON"? Ya que en tu ciclo `while` estás construyendo otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables está esperando datos de tipos `Integer` y tú los estás regresando como `String` desde PHP en tu JSON. Es por eso que estás recibiendo un error como:

> DataTables warning: table id=listado - Invalid JSON response

En tu ciclo `while` convierte todos los tipos de datos `String` necesarios a `Integer`.  Es evidente que el código que pusiste `while` no es el mismo que crea todo el JSON, pero la idea es la misma. Regresa los campos que tienen como llave en tu `array`  (0,1,2,3,4,5,6 y 7) como enteros y su valor en donde sea que uses números también que sean de tipo `Integer`.

Puedes apoyarte de la función `intval` para poder convertir de `String` a `Integer`. Puedes encontrar más referencias sobre esta función en `PHP` en este [enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php).

Comment: Estimado, gracias por su respuesta. Hice lo que me indicaste pero el problema sigue. Pase todo a Integer pero sigue todo igual. Lo mas extraño de todo, que tengo muchas consultas iguales, realizando el mismo proceso y con datatables y es primera vez que me pasa esto. Probe tambien, cambiando las versiones de Datatables, pero no soluciona el problema.

Comment: Vale, muy bien. ¿Podrías indicar entonces el ciclo while correcto el cual arma el JSON que estás poniendo en tu pregunta, compañero? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

reemplaza

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

por

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

La primera linea informa al navegador que estas enviando json, en la segunda pasa todos lo números a tipo numero.

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responder. Hice lo que me comentaste, pero el problema persiste.